# problem with a script to show the ignored hidden and not hidden files (shell)

Tags: shell

im triying to see the ignored hidden files that I have on the .gitignored, I tried to use "git check-ignore .* * " and it worked, but, when I put the code on a script and try to execute it the console shows me this error: " fatal: ..: '..' is outside repository ".

I tried too to use the git status --ignored but it shows a large list of things and not only the ignored files.

Comment: Try `git check-ignore .[^.]* *`

Comment: thnx,  it worked!!!!

Comment: now I'm triying to understand why it works xD, im reading about the wildcards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> tried to use "git check-ignore .* * " and it worked,

Most probably your shell is zsh, or you have `GLOBIGNORE=".:.."`.

> when I put the code on a script and try to execute it the console shows me this error: " fatal: ..: '..' is outside repository ".

The `..` represents the parent directory. `.*` matches `.` followed by anything, so it also matches `..`.

> why it works xD

The `[^<something>]` matches anything **except** `<something>`. `*` matches anything. So `.[^.]*` matches a `.` followed by anything **except** a `.`, followed by `*` anything. It effectively excludes `..`.

Comment: Now i understand how It works the Code and the Wildcard [^], im so grateful!!